# what's the differences between helper and include in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, helper, refinerycms

i'm working on refinerycms, trying to add preview feature to news like pages, i'm trying to include my own helper to a controller, 'include' does not works, but 'helper' works.

sample code:

```
module Refinery
  module News
    module Admin
      class PreviewController < ActionController::Base
        #include LayoutHelper # not ok
        helper LayoutHelper # Ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

i've read the api, helper is working like 'require and include', but i don't know the real difference here.

thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`helper LayoutHelper` does include `LayoutHelper`, but it is included directly **in the template class**.

while `include LayoutHelper`, the module is included **in the controller class**.

You could check the source of `helper`:

```
# File actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb, line 93
def helper(*args, &block)
  modules_for_helpers(args).each do |mod|
    add_template_helper(mod)
  end

  _helpers.module_eval(&block) if block_given?
end
```

Comment: I just saw this answer and I have a follow up if you don't mind xdazz. If Rails already 'includes' the files found in the helper directory in the app/views directory why would you need to use the keyword 'helper' in the controller? I would think you would always want to include (in this case LayoutHelper) in the controller. LayoutHelper should already be accessible in the template by default.

Comment: In answer to the question above, you might have a module defined NOT in /helpers but somewhere else like /lib then it wouldn't be automatically imported by Rails.